# How to delay a block of code without making the whole code wait

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to publish messages to lights every 10 minutes. However, if the person exits the room during these 10 minutes the lights won't turn off because the code is still stuck in the `time.sleep(600)`.
So is there a solution for that?

```
    def publishing():
        while True:
            # the return value of the occupancy sensor is stored in message
            message_occ_sensor = occupancy_sensor.return_message("occupancy_sensor/1")

            # the state of lights ON/OFF is returned
            state_light_tunable = light_tunable.return_message(tunable_light.deviceID+"/Bedroom/stat/POWER")
            state_tunable_with_dimming = light_tunable_with_dimming.return_message(tunable_with_dimming.deviceID + "/Bedroom/stat/POWER")
            state_rgb = light_rgb.return_message(rgb_light.deviceID + "/Bedroom/stat/POWER") 

            # do Ineed here to put all the conditions?
            if message_occ_sensor == "1" and state_light_tunable == "OFF" and state_tunable_with_dimming == "OFF" and state_rgb == "OFF":
                # topics are to be modified and deviceID must be imported from mongoDB
                client.publish(tunable_light.deviceID+"/Bedroom/cmnd/POWER", 1) 
                client.publish(tunable_with_dimming.deviceID+"/Bedroom/cmnd/POWER", 1)
                client.publish(rgb_light.deviceID+"/Bedroom/cmnd/POWER", 1)

                # "device2" can be replaced by another parameter to check whether circadian light is activated
                if is_circadian_Light("device2") == 1 : # I want to add a condition that disables circadian lighting if rgb has a color
                    # publish color temperature
                    client.publish(tunable_light.deviceID+"/Bedroom/cmnd/CIRC", Light.circadianLight())
                    client.publish(tunable_with_dimming.deviceID+"/Bedroom/cmnd/CIRC", Light.circadianLight())
                    client.publish(rgb_light.deviceID+"/Bedroom/cmnd/CIRC", Light.circadianLight())

                    time.sleep(600)
            # time.sleep is preventing the code to execute if smeone exits the roomm during the 10min
            if message_occ_sensor =="0":
                #code to turn off lights after 1 min
                time.sleep(60)
                # In case someone entered the room during one minute or after it
                if message_occ_sensor != "1" and state_light_tunable == "ON" and state_tunable_with_dimming == "ON" and state_rgb == "ON":
                    client.publish(tunable_light.deviceID+"/Bedroom/cmnd/POWER", 0) 
                    client.publish(tunable_with_dimming.deviceID+"/Bedroom/cmnd/POWER", 0)
                    client.publish(rgb_light.deviceID+"/Bedroom/cmnd/POWER", 0)
    pub = threading.Thread(target= publishing)
    pub.start()
```

Comment: Use `Threading.Timer()` to setup a timed thread, which are execute after certain time.

Comment: But this will make the code wait only when it starts, I need to send messages every ten minutes so it needs to be inside the while loop.```Timer(600, publishing)``` will let this thread execute after 10 minutes but not every 10 minutes. @okie

Comment: you mean you want to `publishing()` every 600s?

Comment: you can set up a `while` to repeatedly detect for people while 10 minutes, and split the program that needs to execute after 10min into a function, execute it with `Timer()`, the timer can Pause, stop, and restart if you redefine Timer variable and start it again.